# Using Gulp function throws a recurring error

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have an error when I try to run a function from my old gulpfile.js:

```
$ gulp volumes
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-cli'

$ nvm version
v11.15.0
```

I have to keep this old version of npm in this project, so can't upgrade. I saw that gulp-util is deprecated so I replaced in my gulpfile.js:

```
//replacement packages for gutil:
var colors = require('ansi-colors');
var log = require('fancy-log');
//var gutil = require('gulp-util');
```

How can I sort this out so I can run `gulp volumes`?

### Edit

I tried to install gulp-cli and after that I still have the same issue.

```
$ npm install --global gulp-cli
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
/home/louisro/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/bin/gulp -> /home/louisro/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js

> es5-ext@0.10.62 postinstall /home/louisro/.nvm/versions/node/v11.15.0/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/node_modules/es5-ext
>  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0

+ gulp-cli@2.3.0
added 254 packages from 165 contributors in 18.67s
```

### Edit

```
$ npm list --depth=0 'gulp-cli'
boardline@1.0.0 /home/louisro/Documents/mobileApps/BL/ionic_version
└── gulp-cli@2.3.0
```

### Edit

I just rebooted (just in case) and now I don't have the error any more. And it's not Windows, it's Ubuntu.

Comment: Try `npm install [--global] gulp-cli`. You decide whether or not it should be installed globally or not

Comment: Just tried that (edited the question), still the error persists

Comment: You mean after installing `gulp-cli`, the error message still says it can't find `gulp-cli`? Please include the exact version of gulp-cli you have installed in your question (`npm list --depth=0 'gulp-cli'`)

Comment: yes @smac89 that's what I mean, I still see the same error : Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-cli'.  I just added gulp-cli version in the question. thanks

Comment: Did you try deleting your node_modules folder and running either `npm i` or `yarn`?

Comment: I deleted node_modules before runing npm install yes, same problem occurs.